# What's up with the syntax of "more fool me"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, british-english

In UK English, the idiom "more fool me" means something like "and I'm a fool for doing so".

But how might you try to understand the underlying syntax? Is "fool" an imperative here? A noun? Is the idiom an ellipsis of a longer phrase?

Comment: You are asking an interesting question about how some colloquialisms arise.  It need have nothing to do with syntax.  just the juxtaposition of some words or phrase renders their combined meaning obvious, given the context.  Someone says to me "I'm the cleverest student in the room, to which I might say "the devil you are!", meaning "No, you're not".  How, without the grammar do we know?  "Heaven alone knows!"  Everyone understands "No way".  You can say this is short for "there is no way in which what you have just said can be true (or in which I'm going to do what you just told me to)."

Comment: _The more fool <personal name or pronoun>_ is a construction with a fixed form (_the_ is obligatory, not optional, with _more fool_) and a slot to stick the fool's ID.

Comment: Yes, certainly it has a fixed form. My question was whether the idiom perhaps derives from ellipsis of a longer form, and what that form might be.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's not the everyday definite determiner. It's the dietetic quantifier. The one you get in "*the more the merrier*", and "*all the more reason* ..." or "*all the better for me/all the better to eat you with*"  or "*looking the worse for wear*"

Comment: Originally in this collocation **more** was adjectival (bigger) and not the instrumental as in "the more the merrier".

Comment: @TimR Can you clarify?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore - Is "dietetic" really the term for that _je ... desto ..._ construction? I'd never heard it before in a grammatical context, but I don't see the etymological link. And I'm not sure this is the same thing; it feels to me like you need the second _the_ phrase to balance.

Comment: Do you mean diegetic? Dietetic seems to refer only to “pertaining to dietary matters”.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, it's an 'indexical' degree adverb, where the quantity of the degree concerned can be determined exophorically, from the context or from a phrase or clause which serves as the index, pretty much in the same way as *so, too, this, that, as:* etc: "So big that it fell over" / "too big to fit in the box"  / "as big as I've ever seen". It's unusual in having as it's indirect complement another phrase introduced by the same degree word. It means "this degree more, this degree merrier" or "so much more, so much merrier" etc

Comment: @JohnLawler But notice the second clause is not mandatory: "all the merrier", "the worse for wear" etc don't require the second *the*-phrase.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I'd call all of those "equative", perhaps. In the case of _too_, negative equative. If you wanna say "exophoric", that's fine, though what endophorics are there?

Comment: A-e: But how do you tell that they're "the same" construction? Is there a Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor tome on this construction?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. See my comment to Edwin Ashworth's answer, citing the MED.

Comment: @jogloran typo/autocorrect of ['deictic'](https://glossary.sil.org/term/deixis). Or see [here](https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/ai/Deixis2.pdf) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis).

Comment: See *OEDO* "fool, n.1 & adj." P.4 ["(the) more fool you"](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/fool_n1?tab=factsheet&show-all-quotations=true#1309217450) and the cross-referenced discussion at "more, adj. etc" A.I.1.h, if you have subscription access. If not, I can summarize in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Shakespeare used

- *The more fool you, for laying on my duty*

[[Bianca; The Taming of the Shrew; Act V Scene II line 143, Folger Shakespeare Library](https://www.folger.edu/explore/shakespeares-works/the-taming-of-the-shrew/read/5/2/)]

and

- *Ay, now am I in Arden, the more fool I.*

[Touchstone; *As You Like It*, Act II Scene IV]

I'd hazard it was elliptical even then for say 'The [greater] fool you are' etc, and has become even shorter and with a switch to the objective, often sounding more natural (cf 'It's me / us', 'He is taller than me').

Comment: I notice that you deployed the [sneaky brackets] — is there evidence that "greater" was substitutable for "more" in Early Modern English? That is, would it have been natural to say ?"Thou art the more fool" with the intended meaning "Thou art the greater fool"? If not, it might not be possible to argue that "more" was being used in the capacity of an adjective.

Comment: Compare Middle English. **more** Adjective (7), "more complete, fuller" with "fool",meaning "the worse fool", which meaning continued into Elizabethan times and beyond, until **more** lost that attributive adjectival sense. *And moore fooles ben they that kissen in vileynye.*  https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED28626/track?counter=4&search_id=26933124